# Does Jmeter Perform validation if Keep-Alive check box is ticked

Tags: validation, http, jmeter, keep-alive

I am running performance testing using Jmeter with  keeping Keep-Alive option unchecked. If I keep this option checked I get a lot of errors but without this everything goes smooth. I am just curious to know that in case Keep-Alive is ticked do validation take place on its own i.e. does JMeter have any mechanism to validate before triggering any request using the keep-alive connection or does it just blindly trigger request using that condition without verifying whether the connection is still open or closed from the other side?

NOTE: I want to use Keep-Alive to increase performance but not sure whether I should add validation for it externally via code or Jmeter handles it on its own.

Comment: If you check the check box, Jmeter will set the HTTP Header "Connection: keep-alive", and uncheck will set the "Connection: close", that's it. Jmeter will not check any other things related to the TCP connection (AKAIK, For any generated HTTP request JMETER doesn’t have access to its TCP connection info).